# Interfacing FPGA and a storage device

Tags: fpga, sd

I'm doing this project called "High data rate logger".

The requirements for this project is to sample the 2 analog signals simultaneously.

- 2x channel 14-bit ADC
- Store 60 MSps (mega samples per second), which is roughly 250 MBps sustained write speed
- Storage medium must be able to accommodate 500 GB to 1 TB worth of data

*Storage medium:*

**M.2 PCI-Express** is the latest interface for SSDs (solid state drive). But I am not sure if I can interface an SSD to FPGA through PCIe 2.0 x4 (PCI express generation 2, with 4 lanes) Interface, because of its complications.

*A host that can interface with the above cards:*

Since I am not able to find a processor which has parallel LVDS input lines to be interfaced to ADC, I am thinking to proceed with an FPGA.

But at the other end I have to interface a storage medium like SSD,or SD cards, or NAND flash memory or any other possible solution.

There are many solutions for storage medium with required memory as well as speed. But the problem is interface. Some common memory interfaces are: PCI express, SATA III (6Gbps), SD card interface, etc.

**Therefore I would request anybody to suggest which interface would be feasible, easier and better to interface using FPGA.**

If an appropriate standard interface is selected, I could go ahead with selecting an FPGA and designing a data logger.

Comment: Build the ADC+FPGA into a PCIe card (this sort of thing is available off the shelf) and put it in a PC. Have software transfer from memory-mapped PCI to disk. You may want to compress data on the card to save bandwidth and storage.

Comment: There are cards that have similar requirements already, such as the [Noctar SDR](http://www.pervices.com/products-noctar/).

Comment: I've spent a significant amount of time [writing software](https://github.com/fake-name/pySignalHound) that talks to a [fancy usb-3 spectrum analyser](https://www.signalhound.com/products/bb60c/). I can save a raw datastream at 140 MBytes/sec to a SSD *in python*. Using a PC for this sort of thing is very much a good idea, and it should be very viable.

Comment: Also, USB-3.0 is an option here as well. That would be much more plug+play then PCI-e, though the driver development may be more involved.

Comment: I have developed a "Streaming Optimized SATAController" which is designed for high bandwidth read or write streams to HDDs or SSDs. This controller is capable of handling up to 585 MiB/s. It has also a physical abstraction layer which is vendor and device independent, So you can use this controller with Virtex-5, Kintex-7, Virtex-7, Stratix II, Stratix IV. Other abstraction layer implementations are possible. I won't recommend SATA/ATA8 over PCIe, because you have to develop/debug PCIe and SATA.

Comment: Well, for USB 3.0 you must use an IC, which is the easiest way of transferring data to/from your board. The IP is already available from Cupress and you don't need to write your own driver. 
PCIe can be a solution to, but then you have to implement the protocol's higher levels. I would not recommend SATA or SD interface, unless you have a pretty big budget to buy those IPs.

Comment: @Paebbels Where do I get this product "Streaming Optimized SATAController"? So using SATAController, I'll be able to interface an FPGA with SSD that has SATA III (6Gb/s) interface?

Comment: @FarhadA I never came across an SSD with capacity more than 256GB having USB-3.0 interface. Hence this could be done by parallel interface of 4 SSDs to FPGA right? How about using 4 SD cards with 256GB capacity having 90MB/s write speed? http://www.sandisk.com/products/memory-cards/sd/extremepro-sdxc-sdhc-uhs-3/?capacity=256GB Since I have no specific budget limit for this project I could also consider SD card interfacing option. I have a deadline for this project i.e. 5 months from now. So I want it to be simple and easy to interface.

Comment: @pjc50  I don't think I can use a PC in order to store the data on SSD. Actually, this entire system goes on Flight. It should be as compact as possible.

Comment: It's probably against site policy to do recommendations, but my former employer has experience in doing this kind of thing as a custom device: http://www.argondesign.com/case-studies/2013/apr/29/medical-device-skin-disease-detection/ (7 channels, tens of megabits per channel). PCs can be made quite small, small enough to fit as a backplane under four SSDs.

Comment: @Vicky This controller establishes a SATA link at Gen1/2/3 and reads the HDDs or SSDs response to the ATA8 Identify Device command. If all requirements are met (ATA8, LBA48 addressing mode, DMA support, ...) the interface is ready to transfer data. The controller has 2 FIFO interfaces (RX and TX, each 32 bit wide) and a command interface (command {read, write, flush, ...}, status, error, StartAddress, BurstLength). Additional I wrote a simple MasterTable 'file system' which translates database numbers into offset and length parameters for read and write. If you are interested, then contact me.

Comment: @Vicky Our measurements show that not the SATAcontroller is the limiting factor in transferring data to and from SSD; in most cases it's the SSD or HDD when data is not in cache or pre fetched. We also recognized that speed limiting (insertion of HOLD primitives) is only done by the HDD or SSD, so we achieve a near 99% link utilization.

Comment: @vicky, the issue with SD card is that you need to have an IP for SD interface, and you have to create a special file system to store the data in parallel, unless you just create 4 different files and treat them as independent binary data and merge them later. An alternative is to use a board like Jetson TK1 from NVIDIA that has both USB3 and SATA and connect it to fpga using PCIe.

Comment: According to your suggestion, ADC will be interfaced to FPGA, SSD will be interfaced to Jetson TK1, FPGA and Jetson TK1 will be connected to each other through PCI express??

Comment: -1 Your edit of today seriously harms the question, by removing all of the critical application information from it. As the question now stands, you might as well just use an SD card in SPI mode, since you've stated no requirement which could not be met by that.  Drastically changing questions after they have begun to collect answers is a bad idea, since it makes the answers start to seem irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

We've just built a logger with a data rate of that order of magnitude.  The data are captured on an FPGA and then sent over to a PC using USB3.0 which then writes it to disk.

Assuming your logging latency is not critical (which it usually isn't) I imagine you could do the same.

If you use an [Opal Kelly FPGA board](http://www.opalkelly.com/products/xem6310/), the HDL interfaces and driver development are very straightforward.  I have no connection other than as a satisfied customer!

Alternatively, using a PCIe plugin card with the [Xillybus](http://xillybus.com/) driver provides another straightforward HDL and driver experience. 250MB/s is pushing it for a single lane of PCIe, but as you say a x4 interface will be OK.

Or the full-custom approach of building it all from scratch is of course open to you if you have time, but no money.  I'd still build something to interface to a PC though, rather than trying to go direct to disk from the FPGA.

Comment: Xillybus driver is very expensive. I would prefer building it from scratch. For building it from scratch I would like to know which interface would be less complicated: 1) FPGA-SSD : PCIexpress 2) FPGA-SSD : SATA III 3) FPGA-SD Card : SDXC and SDXC-I (UHS-I) 4) FPGA-SD card : CompactFlash or any other recommended solution???

Comment: What do you mean by building from scratch? You want to write your own IPs for SATA and SDHC?

Comment: @Vicky "which interface would be less complicated"? - FPGA-SSD (SATA III) is a straight forward implementation if you have a working transceiver/physical layer. The command layer is a ATA8 command set which only needs to implement a hand full of commands, the other commands are outdated, for compatibility or for CompactFlash or ATAPI devices. The transport and link-layer FSMs are given in the SATA standard and can be reduced if you spare some features. But the physical layer is hard to debug and need good skills in FPGA and multi clock domain design.

Comment: @Vicky FPGA-SSD (PCIe): I don't know any FPGA dev. board or ext. board which connects a FPGA to a SSD by PCIe (SATAe, M.2) => so there is no test system. I'm not even sure if M.2 SSD cards use the PCIe link. PCIe IPCores can be created by core generators form FPGA vendors, which generate usable code, but you have to write the very complex transaction layer (credit based flow control, reordering, ...), a DMA engine and a command layer on top of this. In contrast to SATA, I think you can't spare so many features to reduce implementation work.

Comment: @Vicky FPGA-SD card (CF): Who want's to implement a legacy protocol? CompactFlash is IDE. Or do you mean CFast? - This is also SATA for the compact flash form factor :)

Answer (score 1):

Alternative strategy: build your own mass storage device.

Have the FPGA write directly to a collection of NAND Flash chips. Don't forget the readback-and-verify phase! You should also be able to arrange to pre-erase the entire array before starting capture (erase is slower than write), and keep your own badblocks list. You can write to multiple chips in parallel if this is required for the write bandwidth. Again, I strongly recommend some form of compression; gzip is suitable for streaming and is lossless.

You can then present a USB interface to a PC which exposes the entire capture as a block device, or a filesystem containing a single "magic" file for the entire capture.